# Disable DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES for an endpoint

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson, null, deserialization

I am adding an endpoint to an app, which receives a json and in spring this is automatically converted to a DTO I created. Many fields can be null, which I set in Kotlin with question mark and it is not a problem when the value is missing in the json, but the problem is when there is explictly "null".

> JSON parse error: Null value for creator property 'trial_period' (index 6); `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES` enabled"

It has been set for some reason in application.yml

```
jackson:
 deserialization:
  fail-on-null-creator-properties: true
```

so I do not want to change it globally, but I need to disable it for this endpoint.
How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is put anotation in your DTO.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
private String trial_period;
```

Comment: Unfourtunately this annotation is for serialization, while I need to deserialize.
I tried @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP), but it does not help in this case.